# Bind an event to a dynamic loading elements on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of divs on my page with the class of `prodct-item-info`. I have some code in jQuery that trigger some code whenever the user clicks on an element that has this class.

Problem is, the page is loading more elements with this class dynamically. When that happens, when I press on this class of the **newly-loaded** element, nothing happens. But if I click on the elements that were created before the dynamic load, it still works.

For instance, **x** is what I loaded at the first time when the page loaded, and **y** is what I added dynamically:

the page has this:

```
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
```

When I click on these, it works fine.

Now I load:

```
y y y y y y y y
```

When I click on these, it doesn't do anything.

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

### EDIT

here is my code:

```
$('.product-item-info').on("click",function() {
        var pid = $(this).find('input').val();
        $.get('product_info.php',{pid:pid},function(data){
            $('#product-lb').html(data).append('<span class="x"><span>X</span></span>');
            $('.x').click(function() {
                $('#dimmer').click();
            });
            $('#dimmer').css({width:$('html').width(),height:$('html').height()});
            $('#dimmer').show();
             center_div($('#product-lb'));
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach/delegate events to dynamically added content. I have used `body` in the below example. You can replace it with `$(document)` as well.

```
$('body').on('click', '.prodct-item-info', function(){
    //put your code here
});
```

If `prodct-item-info` has a parent, you should replace `body` with `#parentID` or `.parentClass` so whenever there is a click on the parent, it will find all children inside it with class `prodct-item-info` and run the code.

Answer (score 2):

How are you targeting your elements?  Something like:

```
$('.someClass').click(function(){
    alert('hi');
});
```

If so, then only the elements that are currently rendered would have the event.  Several options.

One, try targeting your elements using jQuery [**`on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$("#someID").on("click", "a.someClass", function() {
    alert('Do Something);
});
```

Or, after you add the element, apply your event directly to it.

Comment: @kfirba.  Post your script.